# localhost vs. 127.0.0.1 in mysql_connect()

Tags: php, mysql

1. Does using `localhost` in `mysql_connect()` make the connection faster than using `127.0.0.1`?
2. What is the connection type between the PHP script and mySQL (when using the `mysql_connect()` function) ? Is it TCP/IP?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

1. Differs between Windows and Linux. If you use a unix domain socket it'll be slightly faster than using TCP/IP (because of the less overhead you have).
2. Windows is using TCP/IP as a default, whereas Linux tries to use a Unix Domain Socket if you choose localhost and TCP/IP if you take 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Thank you! Why doesn't Apache interact through TCP/IP or socket based connection with PHP?

Comment: Apache uses either mod_php or connects to PHP using TCP/IP or Unix Domain Socket (when configured to run via fastcgi).

Comment: + the nasty thing in linux is when you specify 'localhost' as host, and a specific port, it just ignores the whole port bit and uses the default socket, not something one wants when running multiple servers on a single machine (hence the different port..).

Comment: @Wrikken, that's true, but easily avoidable by using 127.0.0.1:port

Comment: @halfdan: indeed, but something one needs to know _before_ proceeding to demolish some tables :P Ah, live and learn, it was a while back and I'll never forget it.

Comment: also,  127.1  is synonymous with 127.0.0.1 .  try it.

Comment: @djangofan: No? 127.1 is not a valid IP address. It _could_ work as a fallback by the database driver.

Comment: In Windows 10 and 11 is significantly faster to use 127.0.0.1!

Answer (score 21):

"localhost" means local socket connection while 127.0.0.1 is TCP/IP. And yes, sockets are faster than TCP/IP.

Cite from http://pl.php.net/mysql_connect

> Whenever you specify "localhost" or "localhost:port" as server, the MySQL client library will override this and try to connect to a local socket (named pipe on Windows). If you want to use TCP/IP, use "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost". If the MySQL client library tries to connect to the wrong local socket, you should set the correct path as  in your PHP configuration and leave the server field blank.

Comment: TCP/IP is also socket based. I know what you mean, but you'll confuse people with it.

Comment: It could be `Unix-socket connection`

Comment: You are right. I changed this to "local socket" to clarify. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 17):

Nope, the 127.0.0.1 is recommended to use , because Windows 7 has a problem with choosing between IPv6 & IPv4. I tried this and if I used localhost, the page has reloading about 1sec (1,04sec) and when i used 127.0.0.1, the page has reloading 50ms. Both were used under Windows 7.
In Windows XP it doesn´t make difference.

Comment: Had the same experience. Going from localhost to 127.0.0.1 dropped my latency from 1 second to 5 ms. Thanks!

Comment: That's because windows had dropped localhost from the hosts file in later versions so it takes a long time to resolve.

Answer (score 2):

For Unix, add to the client block after 
`[client]`
in /etc/mysql/my.cnf this line :

```
protocol=tcp
```

Answer (score 0):

Php site says:

Note:

> Whenever you specify "localhost" or
>   "localhost:port" as server, the MySQL
>   client library will override this and
>   try to connect to a local socket
>   (named pipe on Windows). If you want
>   to use TCP/IP, use "127.0.0.1" instead
>   of "localhost". If the MySQL client
>   library tries to connect to the wrong
>   local socket, you should set the
>   correct path as in your PHP
>   configuration and leave the server
>   field blank.

I guess the speed difference would be too low that it's something you should'nt be worried about.

Answer (score 0):

For macs, here's the solution:

Connect to MySQL using localhost instead of 127.0.0.1 on a MAC. For a long while now I’ve been connecting to MySQL on my development platform with 127.0.0.1 because for some reason localhost didn’t work. Turns out it’s because 127.0.0.1 uses TCP/IP and localhost uses sockets. The php.ini file points to the wrong place for the mysql.sock so all you have to do is change it, restart apache and voila!

```
Open php.ini: /private/etc/php.ini
Find the following line: mysql.default_socket = /var/mysql/mysql.sock
Replace with: mysql.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
Restart apache: apachectl restart
```

Note: If you don’t have a php.ini file, you need to copy the provided default called php.ini.default

```
sudo cp /private/etc/php.ini.default /private/etc/php.ini
```

via http://madproject.com/general/connect-to-mysql-using-localhost-instead-of-127-0-0-1-on-a-mac/

Answer (score 0):

It is not true that localhost is faster, but is rather a bit slower.

That being said, if you are connecting to someone else; catch my drift?

Who is to say which side of the connection fails harder?  No one.  That:

127.0.0.1 is a faster ping than localhost.  Try on any Terminal.

Comment: Right @Php site!  The difference is insubstantial to most users... LET US NOT LEAVE IT THERE!