# How do I get mysqli_connect() to work?

Tags: php

While running this simple script:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "*****", "********", "***");
if (!$link) {
  printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
  exit();
  }
printf("Host information: %s\n", mysqli_get_host_info($link));
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

on my networksolutions account I received this error

Connect failed: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

I called network solutins tech support twice.  They "re synchronized" the server and we reverified the "connection strings" the function parameters...but no go.  I tried switching from mysql_connect() to mysqli_connect().

I don't know what it could be.  I know there must by thousands of NS customers who do this but did not find an answer on their forum.

Please help.  Anyone interested in working for equity in my website please let me know as well.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your server is on localhost?

Comment: can you give some information about your system?  what OS, is MySQL installed from metapackage?  did you change the configurations at all in my.cnf?

Answer (score 1):

Try `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` to make the connection using TCP/IP rather than through the local socket, which seems to be broken for one reason or another.

[Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715925/localhost-vs-127-0-0-1)

Answer (score 1):

Below code may be help!

```
<?php
/*SERVER database connection*/
    function dbconnect(){
    $connection = mysql_connect('localhost','****','****);
        if(!$connection){
        return false;
        }
        if(!mysql_select_db('database_name')){
        return false;
        }
        return $connection;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using PDO used this example as your basis

```
    <?php
     $orig = $_GET['orig'];
     $des_id = $_GET['des_id'];
            try {
                $dbuser = "kim";
                $dbpass = "kim";
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=destination', $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);    
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT pl_id FROM view_places WHERE name = :name LIMIT 1");

                $stmt->bindParam(':name',$orig); 
                $stmt->execute();
                $result_1 = $stmt -> fetch();
                $res1 = $result_1["pl_id"];  

                $stmt->bindParam(':name', $des_id); 
                $stmt->execute(); 
                $result_2 = $stmt -> fetch(); 
                    $res2 = $result_2["pl_id"];  
                    echo   'origin_number:'.$res1. ', '.'destination_id:'.$res2;
                }   catch(PDOException $e) {
                        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
                }

            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it should be `localhost`? I know that Dreamhost does not allow `localhost` connections to go through -- you have to connect to `mysql.example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Let them know that they not only need to set the proper mysql plugin default socket, but the mysqli plugin default socket.

From my server's `php.ini` config:

```
; Default socket name for local MySQL connects.  If empty, uses the built-in
; MySQL defaults.
mysql.default_socket  = "/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock"
mysqli.default_socket = "/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock"
```

Thus both must be set. I bet they didn't set mysqli.default_socket.