# PHP MYSQL - Difference between 127.0.0.1 and localhost

Tags: php, mysql

I am encountering a strange problem on my imac running OS X. For my frameworks and CMS configuration files if I use host: localhost (in db settings) an error is produced and the CMS/framework cannot connect to the database. However if I replace localhost to 127.0.0.1 everything seems to work fine. Since localhost is resolved to 127.0.0.1 I'd like to know what might be the problem with my php/mysql configurations that is resulting into this behavior.?
I encountered this problem with Wordpress, Cake and CodeIgniter.

Comment: Did you check `/etc/hosts` for a proper entry for `localhost`?

Comment: There is difference, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715925/localhost-vs-127-0-0-1 , http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html and google :)

Answer (score 23):

`localhost` will cause the MySQL client to try a UNIX socket in a standard directory. If that doesn't exist or is somewhere else, you won't be able to connect. `127.0.0.1` always uses a TCP connection.

See the manual, [C.5.2.2. Can't connect to [local] MySQL server](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html).