# Laravel environment config not loading, migration fails - SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, migration, database-migration

My **app/config/database.php** has been setup like this:

```
'mysql' => array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => getenv('DB_HOST'),
    'database'  => getenv('DB_NAME'),
    'username'  => getenv('DB_USER'),
    'password'  => getenv('DB_PASS'),
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
),
```

I have updated my env detection code like this in **bootstrap/start.php**:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function() {
    return file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../.env.production.php')
        ?
        'production'
        :
        'local';
});
```

Now, I have uploaded **.env.production.php** with the following:

```
<?php

return
[
    'DB_HOST' => '178.xxx.xxx.xxx',
    'DB_NAME' => 'USERNAME',
    'DB_USER' => 'PASSWORD',
    'DB_PASS' => 'DBNAME',
];
```

I tested the environment detection like this:

```
[www-data@server]$ php artisan env
Current application environment: production
```

As you can see, it's working as intended. I then proceeded to run the migration like this:

**php artisan migration:install**

When I do, I get the following error:

```
[www-data@server]$ php artisan migrate:install --env=production

  [PDOException]                                    
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory  

migrate:install [--database[="..."]]
```

Any idea why this might be? it looks like it's failing to load the **.env.production.php** file.

Does anyone know how to fix this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That sounds like an inability to connect to the MySQL server, rather than with loading the environment file. Are you certain that the host is correct? 178... looks like an external ip, isn't the database server on your own machine?

Comment: I have a split server server setup. One machine for web/php and another for mysql only. Perhaps I forgot to give the db remote access. Let me check...

Comment: If the problem persists, I'd suggest replacing the getenv() calls in the database configuration file - not permanently, just to confirm whether the server connection is indeed the problem.

Comment: I just checked, the database is setup correctly. Okay, i will try that.

Comment: I removed getenv and typed the access details directly and it worked. So, it looks like the env file is NOT getting loaded as I originally suspected.

Comment: What's weird is, i have a local environment setup on my dev machine and exact same setup works with *.env.local.php* - just not on the production server.

Comment: Right... that's really weird, then. Sorry for sidetracking you, hope you are able to find the error eventually.

Comment: Actually, I think I may have figured it out. Laravel 4 defaults to naming the environment production, so the file should be just .env.php, not .env.production.php. Worth a try at least. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Laravel 4 docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration) it states that it needs to be `.env.php` on your production server.

> Now, on your production server, create a .env.php file in your project
>   root that contains the corresponding values for your production
>   environment. Like the .env.local.php file, the production .env.php
>   file should never be included in source control.

So simply change your environment detection code to this

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function() {
    return file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../.env.php')
        ?
        'production'
        :
        'local';
});
```

Note - you still use `.env.local.php` on your development server.