# PDOException SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory when trying to migrate

Tags: php, laravel-5, vagrant, homestead, laravel-5.1

This question has already been asked multiple times, however I can't seem to get it to work anyway.

I am trying to migrate a migration I just created with laravel to my freshly created database. However, everytime I type in `php artisan migrate` I'm getting the above error

> PDOException SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

**What I have done is the following:**

Create a database and a database user

```
CREATE DATABASE openletter CHARACTER SET utf8;
CREATE USER 'openletter'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'secret';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON openletter.* TO 'openletter'@'%';
```

Add these configs to the .env

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=openletter
DB_USERNAME=openletter
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Creating the migration

```
php artisan make:migration create_letters_table --create=letters
```

Migrating the migration

```
php artisan migrate
```

Then, the above listed error came.

**What I tried**

Restart the MySQL Service: `vagrant ssh && sudo service mysqld restart`
Reloading Homestead/Vagrant: `vagrant reload --provision`
Setting the database config in `config/database.php`

Many people telling others to link the mysql socket, but those people are refferencing MAMP or XAMPP or sth. else. I'm however using Homestead

What could also be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried this solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723803/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: My `APP_ENV` is `local` so I did `php artisan migrate --env=local` but the same error persists

Comment: Have you tried "composer dump-autoload"? It often helps with migration classes that cannot be found in my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok guys, I fixed the issue. I'm an idiot and should be ashamed. The reason it didn't work, was because I wasn't in my vagrant machine.

After doing `vagrant ssh` navigating to my project `cd work/OpenLetter` and doing `php artisan migrate` it worked of course.

Comment: Of course! Honest mistake. For me, getting the environment ready involves `source ~/.zshrc` then 
`homestead up --provision` then
`homestead ssh`, of course making sure we are in the right dir.