# Vagrant + Laravel database access

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I have faced the same problem as reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723803/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory), but instead of the given solution, I could solve by just changing the port from `3306` to `33060` and everything worked fine in command line as I ran `php artisan:migrate`.

however, if I change again from `33060` to `3306` I can access my application through the browser but not through the command line again.

I thought that it might be the vagrant, so I created an environment variable for
each of the agents and placed them in my `database.php` file, as below:

```
'mysql' => [
  'driver'    => 'mysql',
  'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost') .':'. (php_sapi_name() === 'cli' ? env('DB_PORT_CLI') : env('DB_PORT')),
  'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
  'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
  'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
  'charset'   => 'utf8',
  'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
  'prefix'    => '',
  'strict'    => false,
],
```

Now, both browser and CLI are working, but still I think it's not the best solution.

Has anyone faced the same problem? how could I solve it neatly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you run in browser domain mapped into Vagrant server? I've been using Vagrant for a while and had no problems with DB and ports. Standard 3306 is working fine in Laravel config when you connect to database located also in Vagrant

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek you remembered me that I also have a vagrant vm that is working. I'll try to copy it and give some feedback. thanks!

Comment: I have the exact same issue.