# Apache, PHP, MySQL, PDO, Permission denied , laravel

Tags: php, mysql, apache, laravel, pdo

I'm working on a fun little PHP web application (a manager for my repeating, daily tasks), mostly for the exercise.  The 'production' server is a bit limiting, and I cannot view httpd's (Apache's) error logs there, so I've set up my own local httpd as a development server (just good sense).  However, my web app makes use of a MySQL database.  I will create a local one eventually, but I thought, to make things easier to start, I would just use the remote one. 
`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Permission denied`.

This is what came back each time I tried running the web application from my local httpd.  I'm using PHP's PDO database interface, and its mysql driver, and it works when deployed on the remote server.  I made sure that my remote server had permissions for my local user.  I tested connecting from my local machine from the mysql client, and it worked.  I tested the PHP connection statement from the command-line and ... it worked.  It is only causing a problem when running within the web application.

Please tell me how to solve this issue. This is the site on which i am getting error `pickprogress.com`

Comment: Maybe in localhost you have "user: root; password: ;" and in production you have "user: normal-user; password: asdlk2423dgfgklkl" and you don't change these parameters? Show more code to help

Comment: Can you include the code that returns the error?

Comment: no i am trying to solving this issue since last 6 hours checked each and every thing. changed host name to 127.0.0.1 checked user name nd paswrds. And if user name and paswrods are wrong then it gives another exception not this

Comment: Have you reffered this link? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723803/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Log into your mysql instance, and check what grants the user you're trying to connect with has. I think the user is probably limited to connections from a specific IP and won't accept your connection from local as a result.

Comment: ravi this error is different i am having exception related to permission denied. The link you gave it's related to exception `PDOException SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory`

Comment: what can be the solution?

Comment: The remote mysql is it a shared hosting?

Comment: YES IT'S A SHARE HOSTING

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some various server provider gives us their database server name. And instead of writing `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` we have to write their given server name.

I was trying to solve this problem since last 8 hours but didn't found single solution but anyhow I have now solved it.

Answer (score 0):

IN my setuation .env file has the following:

DB_HOST=**127.0.0.1**

i change it to this:

DB_HOST=**localhost**

and it's working ...

i'm in local machine (linux fedora ) with apache server