# Laravel 5.2 artisan 'migrate' is not working

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead, laravel-artisan

The title description pretty much says it all. When I run `php artisan migrate` inside my project's folder (in my Macbook), it errors out with the following:

```
  [PDOException]                                    
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

I have taken the time to browse around the error and try some fixes, but the only way I got it to work is if I actually ssh into my vagrant box (homestead) and run the migration from there, but I am trying to actually run it from my terminal window locally without ssh-ing into homestead.

Do you know what can be causing this problem?

Thank you for all your help in advance!

Cheers!

### UPDATE:

Before I thought it was due to MAMP being installed in my computer. But currently I am not using any servers or anything like that that can be messing with port 3306 since I have a fresh El Capitan install.

Comment: you should be running that from the vm

Comment: why? cant you run it from the terminal without ssh-ing?

Comment: Have you configured the `.env` database global variables ? ie `DB_HOST` ,`DB_DATABASE` , `DB_USERNAME` , `DB_PASSWORD` as per your database ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the answers here: [PDOException SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723803/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory)

You'll need to change the hostname in your mysql config according to this:

> Laravel 4: Change "host" in the app/config/database.php file from
>   "localhost" to "127.0.0.1"
>
> Laravel 5: Change "DB_HOST" in the .env file from "localhost" to
>   "127.0.0.1"
>
> Laravel w/ Homestead: Use the directions above for the Laravel version
>   you are using BUT change "localhost" to the IP address specified in
>   Homestead.yaml. The default is "192.168.10.10" instead of "127.0.0.1"

Answer (score 1):

i also faced this problem. i solved this problem.

Just edit your .env file. 
Change `DB_HOST=localhost` to `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1`

and the funny think is, the reverse is true in some cases.