# Laravel 5.2 composer update error

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Is somebody get `composer update` error today?

Here is my error:

When I run `composer update` I got this

> php artisan clear-compiled
>     [PDOException]
>     SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
>     Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error
>
> [RuntimeException]
>   Error Output:
>   update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--] []...

Also `php artisan` command doesn't work, too.

Comment: did you run command in application directory?

Comment: Yes, of course. I tried my other projects and works great. I really dont understand why...

Comment: Do you use SqLite for your project? If so, does directory for this file and file itself exists?

Comment: No. I am using mysql. I also checked my database folder I dont have sqlite database file. @MarcinNabiałek

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/20733001/3348994