# Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (PDO)

Tags: php, pdo

Hello guys I got in to problem. I got 2 php files

Core php(Where error occurs):

```
<?php
include('getSecondDropDown.php');

$arrayForSecondDropdown[] = functionName();
foreach($arrayForSecondDropdown as $v){
       echo "<option value='" . $v['Country_ID'] ."'>" . $v['Country_Name'] ."</option>";
}
?>
```

getSecondDropDown.php:

```
<?php
    include('config.php');
    function functionName(){
    $Region_ID =$_POST['Region_ID'];
    $option="";
              try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Country_ID, Country_Name FROM Countries WHERE Region_ID ='".$Region_ID."'"); 
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

    foreach($stmt as $v) { 

    echo "<option value='" . $v['Country_ID'] ."'>" . $v['Country_Name'] ."</option>";

}
              }
              catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
    }
        echo $option;

  ?>
```

Full error code(Shown in web console - sources) :

```
Country: <select name="Country_ID" id="Country_ID" form="ServiceForm">
Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory<option value=''></option></select></br>
```

Comment: Possibly a wrong server name? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723803/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory has some more info

Comment: @Carl with connection anything is right, becouse in other .php all works fine, and code are same.

Comment: check your $servername variable

Comment: @YourCommonSense Checked it works. In other php files, it's same, but works. Only in this one file dosn't work.