# How to connect database on server with project on local host? (xampp)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I have a project on local host (xampp) and I want o connect database on server (hostinger.com) with this project, but I don't know? Can anyone help me? Thank so much.

[image: my .env]

Comment: You need to put `Database name` and `database host` in your `.env` file or directly in your `database.php`

Comment: What does not work?

Comment: @RobinDirksen It's seem to error 
PDOException in Connector.php line 55:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.

Comment: @FaouziOudouh above is my env file and I putted correct db_name and db_host

Comment: Did you setup a "allow host", this is you public ip. https://www.hostinger.co.uk/knowledge-base/839 http://www.whatsmyip.org/

Comment: @RobinDirksen I didn't known setup allow host. Can you help me that?

Comment: Why won't you export DB and build with code on localhost? I don't think it(your way) a right thing to do - just my idea.

Comment: @Dung for the best performance you need to run the database on you local machine, otherwise the requests may take 3 times so long...

Comment: @BuiVietHuong I want this project upload to server not change database config.

Comment: @RobinDirksen ok, thanks for your idea. I only want this is easer when I upload this project to server.

Comment: @Dung you can setup a .env file that's only for your server, and you have a local .env file.

Comment: @RobinDirksen I will note it when I deploy my app.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please use it may be working. Put value DB_DATABASE,DB_USERNAME & DB_PASSWORD see below.

APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://hostinger.com/
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE= your database name here
DB_USERNAME= your database username here
DB_PASSWORD= your database password here

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Comment: I did this but it still not working. And here is error from page SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.

Comment: Please flow it.                                                                                        Laravel 4: Change "host" in the app/config/database.php file from "localhost" to "127.0.0.1"

Laravel 5: Change "DB_HOST" in the .env file from "localhost" to "127.0.0.1"

Comment: Please see link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723803/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Thanks you so much. Your link is useful with me.