# Adding data into the database not working in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am using laravel 5.3
I have created a view to create posts and am trying to add data to the table with save method but it is giving me SQL error.

> **SQL Error:** QueryException in Connection.php line 770: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory `(SQL: insert into posts (title, body, updated_at, created_at) values (Test, sdfhgfj, 2017-02-06 07:43:54, 2017-02-06 07:43:54))`

**view/posts.create.blade.php:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8 offset-2">
     <h1>Create New Post</h1>
      <hr>
        {!! Form::open(['route' => 'posts.store']) !!}
          <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('title', 'Title:', ['class' => 'control-label']) }}
            {{ Form::text('title', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
            {{ Form::label('body', 'Body:', ['class' => 'control-label']) }}
            {{ Form::textarea('body', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
          </div>
        {{Form::submit('Create',array('class'=>'form-submit btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg'))}}
        {!! Form::close() !!}
   </div>
</div>
```

**web.php(route file):**

```
Route::resource('posts','PostController');
```

**app/http/Post.php(Model):**

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    //
}
```

**PostController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  //validate
  $this->validate($request,array(
    'title'=>'required|max:255',
    'body'=>'required'
  ));

  //Store 
  $post = new Post;
  $post->title = $request->title;
  $post->body = $request->body;
  $post->save();

  //redirect
  return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post->id);
}
```

I have also added use `App/Post`, in top after namespaces in `PostController.php` but code does not runs after save method. Also, `php artisan migrate` command runs successfully and tables are created in database, but still facing issue with save.

Comment: SQL Error: QueryException in Connection.php line 770: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: insert into `posts` (`title`, `body`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Test, sdfhgfj, 2017-02-06 07:43:54, 2017-02-06 07:43:54))

Comment: include namespace for class Post and check if the db table 'posts' exist.

Comment: @malutki5200 table for 'posts' exists in database and I have also added 'use App\Post;' in PostController.php

Comment: Can we see your database configuration.

Comment: DB_CONNECTION=mysql
                    DB_HOST=localhost
                    DB_PORT=3306
                    DB_DATABASE=blog
                    DB_USERNAME=root
                    DB_PASSWORD=

Comment: Here is a solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723803/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Whats the configuration for your `.env` file

Comment: @VaheGalstyan thanks man
I have changed host from "localhost" to "127.0.0.1" in .env as well as config/database.php and then restarted server and server now runs on "http://127.0.0.1:8000" instead of "http://localhost:8000"

Answer (score 0):

I have changed host from "localhost" to "127.0.0.1" in .env as well as config/database.php and then restarted server and server now runs on "http://127.0.0.1:8000" instead of "http://localhost:8000"

And it works well!!!