# Cant run PhP artisan migrate on AWS LAMP server

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, amazon-web-services

I am trying to deploy a Laravel project on an AWS instance. I followed this tutorial to get the web server and mysql setup:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html

Then installed composer , deployed the Laravel project on the instance ,changed some http configs and some other settings and got it working ,

Now I am trying to migrate my local database using , `php artisan migrate`

Every time I try though, I get  :

```
 [PDOException]
 SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

I tried some solutions in this question :[PDOException SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723803/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory), but didn't succeed

Here is how my .env file looks like for database configs:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=<db end point>
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=projectFirst
DB_USERNAME=<userName>
DB_PASSWORD=<password>
```

Comment: Is the `DB_HOST` value pointing to a local or remote instance?

Comment: its pointing to my rds instance on aws

Comment: what is your environment in env file?

Comment: I tried both local ,and production doesn't change things

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by running

Composer update

Also had to point the DB host to 'localhost '