# php artisan migrate - SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: laravel

I went through the laravel to-do app and am stuck at the php artisan migrate part. I know this question has been posted many times here already but I feel like I've tried many suggestions that just aren't working--changing the host to localhost and 127.0.0.1, generating the key for the .env file, adding in a socket, forcing the migration, etc. Below is a screenshot of my .env and database files for your reference. Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlTZZ.png)

Answer (score 2):

So because you're using MAMP, there's a few caveats which are probably not clear, such as MAMP not using a normal UNIX Socket.

But to fix your problem, you'll need to do the following in your database config file, replace `unix_socket` with this:

```
'unix_socket'   => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
```

You may also have to run:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Incase your config files have been cached previously.

Comment: I changed the unix_socket with what you suggested above and also cleared the cache but am still getting the error message --   [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or director

Comment: @emily try techytimo solution by putting the path in .env file

Answer (score 1):

Had this same issue since I am using MAMP. I am on laravel 5.5 so my database.php has this line under the `mysql` directive:

```
'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
```

The solution was to add the DB_SOCKET option which was missing on the environment file:

```
DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem using Laravel 5.7.3 with XAMPP for OS X (not XAMPP-VM) and managed to solve this by referring to Kyo's solution in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723803/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory).

I updated line 49 in config/database.php:

```
'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
```

with

```
'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock'),
```

I also tried TechyTimo's solution above and this worked for me as well. I assume it would be better to use this solution since all configurations are kept in one file.

Comment: i want to try this solution @Claret15 mentions since im on xampp but mysql socket file is missing for me. i was expecting to find it here:
/opt/lampp/var/mysql