# this php code works in localhost but not on server?

Tags: php, sql, json, ajax, xml

we are making an collage project that is about to store website name , category , and details so we are done with website and now we want to make app that will communicate with server through `API` . we had simple code like this in php script when data is added into database `echo json_encode(true)` . as android programmers know , retrofit library use key value pair type mechanism so we updated code with following.

```
<?php

    $websiteName = $_POST['website_name'];
    $websiteCategory = $_POST['website_cat'];
    $websiteDetails = $_POST['website_details'];

    try {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=website' , 'root' , '');
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO website_data SET website_name = :website_name , website_cat = :website_cat , website_details = :web_del';

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':website_name' ,$websiteName);
        $stmt->bindValue(':website_cat' ,$websiteCategory);
        $stmt->bindValue(':web_del' ,$websiteDetails);
        $stmt->execute();

        echo json_encode(['response' => 'true']);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $msg = $e->getMessage();
        echo json_encode(['response' => $msg]);
    }
?>
```

and here is javascript code that performs operation with ajax

```
function sendData(websiteName , categoryName , websiteDetails){
    var params = 'website_name='+websiteName+'&website_cat='+categoryName+'&website_details='+websiteDetails;
    var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xml.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.status == 200 && this.readyState == 4){
            var response = this.responseText;
            var responseJson = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log('resonse from server' , responseJson['response']);
            if(responseJson['response'] == 'true'){
                addToCurrent(websiteName , categoryName , websiteDetails);
            }else{
                alert('unfortunatley data could not added succesfully');
            }
        } else{
            console.log('there is some problem with sever');
        }
    }
    xml.open('POST' , '../php/addNewWebsite.php' , true);
    xml.setRequestHeader('Content-type' , 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xml.send(params);
}
```

this is working as indented in localhost good but it is not working in our free server it shows the `alert('unfortunatley data could not added succesfully');`i do not know why does this happening. we have free server and domain from the awardspace.com

**UPDATE**

here is the error message i am getting from the `server SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory`
Thank You .

Comment: Make sure that the path '../php/addNewWebsite.php' is correct and check that the default directory is correctly setup in the server's .htaccess file.

Comment: have you added right credential of server in connection . on this line 
new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=website' , 'root' , '');

Comment: @Gaurav yes i have added right credential otherwise it would not work in localhost (xampp)

Comment: @Shaam i can not access .htaccess file due to free server but it was working perfect before updating the code , i am thinking to replace these files with old one .

Comment: Do server and localhost have the same database credential ??

Comment: @Gaurav no , server credential have been changed according need but it was working fine with old codes and in this new codes i have replace localhost with server host and vice versa .

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered similiar issues in the past. You should try changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`, assuming your MySQL server is running on the same box.

My belief is that the issue that you are encountering is that "localhost" uses a UNIX socket and can not find the database in the standard directory. However "127.0.0.1" uses TCP , which essentially means it runs through the "local internet" on the machine, being much more reliable than a UNIX socket.

Comment: @buttface614 you are saying right about localhost but it is not useful in my case my codes working fine on localhost but not on the server .

Comment: @communityPeople so i had no choice , i made another account in that site and uploaded code and guess it is working fine . i could not figure out what happend with old website but in the new site   code is running as intended . both server have same code file though it was not working . thank you all the community people who try to help me and give me suggestion thank you