# create($table) with pdo the error SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql, datatable, create-table

On my local computer the code is working and but it's not working on the free hosting (www.aba.ae).

Error message with pdo

```
(SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory)
```

code php:

```
function create($table)
{
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root" ;
    $password = "********";
    $dbname = "*****"; 
    try { 
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername; dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table ( 
               `id` INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
               `name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
               `email` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
               `phone` INT(15) NULL,
               `comment` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
               `datee` DATE NOT NULL)"; 
        $conn->exec($sql);
    } catch(PDOException $e) 
    {
        echo $sql . "<br> " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $conn = null;
}
```

Comment: Which line is the error happening on?

Comment: localhost is most likely not the correct hostname and it's definitely not root..check the details the host gave you.

Comment: Did you Google the error? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723803/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Depending on the type of DB, could be that the database name is misspelled.

Comment: You should probably add some error checking on the connection statement as well as the query.