# Symfony3.4/Doctrine migrations - An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: symfony, doctrine, migration

I'm trying to run Doctrine migrations in Symfony3.4 project however I stuck for a couple of days now.
Does anyone faced the same issue? How to make this work?
Thanks in advance!

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate Version20180909015642

19:03:19 ERROR     [console] Error thrown while running command 
"doctrine:migrations:migrate". Message: "An exception occured in 
driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory" ["exception" 
=> Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException { …},"command" => 
"doctrine:migrations:migrate","message" => "An exception occured in 
driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory"] []

In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 103:

  An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file 
or directory  

In PDOConnection.php line 47:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory  

In PDOConnection.php line 43:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

Bundle is registered in AppKernel.php

```
new Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle(),
```

In config.yml

```
doctrine_migrations:
    dir_name: "%kernel.root_dir%/DoctrineMigrations"
    namespace: Application\Migrations
    table_name: doctrine_migration_versions
    name: Application_Migrations_Default
```

app/DoctrineMigrations/Version20180909015642.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Application\Migrations;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\AbstractMigration;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema;

/**
 * Auto-generated Migration: Please modify to your needs!
 */
class Version20180909015642 extends AbstractMigration
{


    /**
     * @param Schema $schema
     */
    public function up(Schema $schema)
    {
        //...
    }

    /**
     * @param Schema $schema
     */
    public function down(Schema $schema)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723803/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 0):

The console commands have help options `-h` which are very helpful.

```
 php bin/console doctrine:migrations -h
```

Have said that, for migrating up to specific migration file you should use timestamp of the final migration file like bellow

```
 php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate 20180909015642
```

For executing specific migration file though, the `execute` command should be used; like following

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:execute 20180909015642 --up
```

Get help on specific command to see full explanation and examples

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:execute -h

php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate -h
```