# Gitlab Ci Laravel PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: php, laravel, continuous-integration, gitlab

My laravel tests run perfectly fine on my machine, but when running on gitlab-runner via docker I see this on all my tests:

```
...
Caused by
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

/builds/project-0/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70
/builds/project-0/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:46
/builds/project-0/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/MySqlConnector.php:24
/builds/project-0/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/ConnectionFactory.php:182
/builds/project-0/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:916
/builds/project-0/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:941
/builds/project-0/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:399
/builds/project-0/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:325
/builds/project-0/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:657
/builds/project-0/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:624
/builds/project-0/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:333
/builds/project-0/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/MySqlBuilder.php:99
/builds/project-0/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/MySqlBuilder.php:48
/builds/project-0/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/FreshCommand.php:73
/builds/project-0/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/FreshCommand.php:46
/builds/project-0/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:29
/builds/project-0/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:87
/builds/project-0/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:31
/builds/project-0/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:572
/builds/project-0/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:183
/builds/project-0/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:255
/builds/project-0/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:170
/builds/project-0/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:886
/builds/project-0/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:262
/builds/project-0/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:145
/builds/project-0/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php:89
/builds/project-0/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php:188
/builds/project-0/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:250
/builds/project-0/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/PendingCommand.php:136
/builds/project-0/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/PendingCommand.php:218
/builds/project-0/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithConsole.php:55
/builds/project-0/tests/RefreshAndSeedDatabase.php:61
/builds/project-0/tests/RefreshAndSeedDatabase.php:20
/builds/project-0/tests/TestCase.php:21
/builds/project-0/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php:71
...
```

Here's my `.env.testing`:

```
...
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=secret
...
```

and my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: composer

stages:
- setup
- test
- deploy

phpunit:
  stage: test
  image: epcallan/php7-testing-phpunit:7.2-phpunit6

  services:
  - mysql:5.7

  variables:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret

  before_script:
  - apt-get install -y libpng-dev libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev
  - docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/
  - docker-php-ext-install gd

  script:
  - cp .env.testing .env
  - composer install
  - php artisan key:generate
  - php artisan passport:key
  - php vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-text --colors=never --coverage-html=public/tests/coverage
```

I've tried changing `DB_HOST` to `127.0.0.1` like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22927341/3403924), but that didn't help.

A solution that's worked on my other laravel projects is to set `DB_HOST` to `mysql`, which usually works, but doesn't this time. I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this fixed by setting `DB_HOST=mysql` in the `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

variables:

```
    MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead

    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret

    DB_HOST: mysql
```

This overrides the variables set in `.env.testing` to allow the tests to run without any further configuration on the host machine.