# Trying to run migration on Laravel getting an error

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations

Hey just started to use Laravel, however, cannot run migration. I followed the documentation on laravel website and installed XXAMP. The server is running and when i type http://192.168.64.2/phpmyadmin it takes me to phpmyadmin dashboard. Also successfully created database.
 However, when i try to run migration it gives me following

```
php artisan migrate -v

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = tutorial and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at /Users/bobo/Desktop/Developers/php/myfirstsite/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668| 

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory")
      /Users/bobo/Desktop/Developers/php/myfirstsite/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

  2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=tutorial", "root", "12345", [])
      /Users/bobo/Desktop/Developers/php/myfirstsite/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70
```

Here is my env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=tutorial
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723803/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory for solution to this problem

Comment: I am using XAMPP

Comment: Hi are you still experiencing this issue? also why are you accessing your xammp server on http://192.168.64.2 instead of http://localhost or 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: @MazinoSUkah It comes as this by default, maybe because I am using Postgresql as well for my another app.

Comment: hmmm i don't understand why it should be accessible over that ip, can you try to use localhost and create the database on http://localhost:8000/phpmyadmin. Then run your migrations again.