# How to fix " php artisan migrate" error in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, bash, migration

I'm setting up my project after restoring my macOS Mojave and getting an error. I install MySQL with homebrew.

I tried to change localhost to 127.0.0.1 but it didn't help me

This is my .env

- DB_CONNECTION = mysql,
- DB_HOST = localhost
- DB_PORT = 3306
- DB_DATABASE= example
- DB_USERNAME=root
- DB_PASSWORD=

This is an error message

> 1   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No
>   such file or directory")
>         /Documents/cleaning/example/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:31
>
> 2   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or
>   directory")
>         /Documents/cleaning/example/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:27

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDOException SQLSTATE\[HY000\] \[2002\] No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723803/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Not correct your config of .env file for database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not exist .env file ,create one from .env-example and in set declare database configs and run command 
If you not callin key:generate

```
php artisan key:generate
```

If you have been all,exec below command

```
php artisan config:cache
```

And try

```
php artisan migrate
```

If your still get error try localhost or http://127.0.0.1 ,edit it 
And again run below command

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Import 
-2002 error given error when user and password wrong to host

Answer (score -2):

1. Try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost in your .env file.
2. Run `php artisan cache:clear`
3. `php artisan migrate --env=production`

Above steps works for me.