# impossible to connect to the database

Tags: mysql, laravel, macos

I am on a mac machine, i have problem to connect to the database,
i try to connect it with the terminal it works pretty well, but when i run it i have always an error:

When i run my app for any query i have an error, example:

```
{"error":"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `project` where `disabled` <> 1)"}
```

My .env file:

```
APP_NAME=linkedQare
APP_ENV=127.0.0.1
APP_KEY=base64:7JgSptYCl1RJ+AkY6WzQzbTLRply1rZIcf19rgvwvgQ=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=https://127.0.0.1:8000
VUE_URL=https://127.0.0.1:8080

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1:3306
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=linkedQare
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

I tried to change localhost to 127.0.0.1 but it doesn' t make any difference

I am using mysql 8 also, tried to uninstall, reinstall without any difference also

I think the connection to the database is not working as even if i change the database password, or remove it to try i get the same error message.
when i run the command php artisan passport:install i have this error:

```
Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory")
      /Users/chu/Documents/linkedqare/linkedqare-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

  2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=linkedQare", "root", "root", [])
      /Users/chu/Documents/linkedqare/linkedqare-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70
```

My same app works pretty good in a windows machine

Comment: Remove the port from the host in your env: `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1`

Comment: Are you sure your mysql is started ? Maybe try localhost instead of IP

Comment: @VincentDecaux yes it is started, i connect good in terminal

Comment: @DigitalDrifter i tried it also, no success

Answer (score 4):

The error message showing that MySQL connection via socket is tried.
In the context of Laravel (artisan), you probably want to use a different environment.

Try changing `APP_ENV=local`
or

```
php artisan migrate --env=production
```

Another [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723803/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory) answer showing the same error with you.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer, need to change the database.php file
answer can be found here: [PDOException SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723803/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory)