# PDO connection failed but working in MYSQL workbench

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I enable mysql service on XAMPP in my windows PC.
No password set into the mysql service, i can connect mysql with MYSQL workbench by
`Hostname: localhost` , `Port: 3306` and `Username: root`

but when i try into my php script below

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully";
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

It gives me `Connection failed`. What is problem?

Comment: Is there any output from `$e->getMessage()`?

Comment: Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723803/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory as it should help (most likely dupe)

Comment: Try changing `$servername` to `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must send an empty password :

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);
```

Comment: *This parameter is optional for some PDO drivers*