# Laravel 8 Migrate Error Using XAMPP Database on MAC

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, xampp

I'm using Laravel Framework 8.20.1 & XAMPP For MySQL Database on MAC and when i run this command: php artisan migrate it display an error message not sure why ?

.env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=atamana_db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = atamana_db and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:678
    674▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    675▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    676▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    677▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 678▕             throw new QueryException(
    679▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    680▕             );
    681▕         }
    682▕ 

      +33 vendor frames 
  34  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20733001/7181149

Comment: does ```php artisan migrate:fresh``` work? be careful - this does a rollback for all your migrations and applies them again

Comment: Already try both solutions before but it did not work at all. This is a fresh install project for testing so i do not mind to rollback anything

Comment: I Have install and configure MySQL Base on This Article but still the same problem
https://medium.com/macoclock/mysql-on-mac-getting-started-cecb65b78e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly recommend using Homebrew to set up MySQL instead.

Visit https://brew.sh/

Open your terminal and run the command on the brew website to install it.

Then install mysql using

```
brew install mysql
```

Start MySQL by running

```
brew services start mysql
```

Create your database by running

```
mysql -u root -p
CREATE DATABASE atamana_db;
```

Since PHP doesn't yet understand caching_sha2_password, try mysql_native_password use This Command:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

Then hit Control + C to exit MySQL

Try running your migration again.