# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `posts`) with sail docker container

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker, laravel-8

I am pretty new to Laravel but have worked with several frameworks in the past. I am using a Linux development host and have created a docker container as per documentation using:

```
curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash
```

After that I have ramped it up using:

```
cd example-app
./vendor/bin/sail up
```

I have used migrations to create a post table, which worked fine, and used tinker to add some sample entries. Also, that worked without any issues. But when I am trying to read all table entries in a Controller using the model, I get a MySQL connection refused error.

> ```
> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `posts`)
> ```

After quite a bit of research, I have not been able to solve it. I have tried various solution proposed in different other threads, like:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

no success. I also changed IP address 127.0.0.1 to localhost in .env or towards the docker service mysql as described. All of that with NO success so far.

### Summary of what is working:

- php artisan migrate works fine
- php artisan tinker works fine
- phpMyAdmin or other db tools can connect without issues to the DB
- ramping up a development server with `php artisan serve` does work and my controller returns table entries as JSON (as expected)

### What does NOT work:

- PostControler and Post::all() results in connection refused when running in docker environment

Has anyone had the same issue as this. It seems everything is setup correctly as everything works on the console and also when firing up a development server. However when running the normal app at http://locahost/posts (for the post controller index) it returns a connection refused.

### Environment information

Laravel version: 8.40.0
Laravel locale:en
Laravel config cached: false
PHP version: 8.0.3

### config entries

.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=dbname
DB_USERNAME=user
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

docker-compose.yml

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.0/app
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - redis
            - selenium
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping"]
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sailredis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
    meilisearch:
        image: 'getmeili/meilisearch:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MEILISEARCH_PORT:-7700}:7700'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmeilisearch:/data.ms'
        networks:
            - sail
    mailhog:
        image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_PORT:-1025}:1025'
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
        networks:
            - sail
    selenium:
       image: 'selenium/standalone-chrome'
       volumes:
            - '/dev/shm:/dev/shm'
       networks:
           - sail
    phpMyAdmin:
        image: 'phpmyadmin:latest'
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
        links:
            - 'mysql:db'
        depends_on:
            - mysql
        networks:
            - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sailmysql:
        driver: local
    sailredis:
        driver: local
    sailmeilisearch:
        driver: local
```

Post Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Post;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return Post::all();
        //return view('posts.index');

    }
...
```

Answer (score 7):

I have found a solution to the issue.

Changing to localhost did end trying to use a socket, which apparently did not work. I even added the docker mysql socket to the php.ini as default_socket, but it did not resolve anything.

### Solution:

I have changed localhost/127.0.0.1 to the real IP address of my machine and now everything works as expected.

Comment: I have no idea why this works when every, every other comment, post, blog and whatever the fudge else says host is either 127.0.0.1 or localhost, I don't know who you are but thank you you beautiful b*****d

Answer (score 2):

As the OP mentioned he uses IP address of container, it's not a good practice to do that since the IP address may change.

Change your `.env` file to:

```
DB_HOST=mysql
```

And it will connect this exact container.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and fixed just by converting `DB_HOST` constant in the .env File FROM `127.0.0.1` into `localhost`
*JUST DO THIS AS GIVEN IN THE BELOW LINE*
`DB_HOST = localhost`.

No need to change anything into `config/database.php`

Don't forget to run

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: Thanks for that recommendation, but this leads me to another error, which is  

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from `posts`)`  

Any idea on that one?  
I am also getting this now when using  tinker

Comment: @JürgenNeyses The error message indicates that a MySQL connection via socket is tried (which is not supported).

Comment: look for the database.php file in the config folder in laravel project folder and check its have localhost instead of 127.0.01

Comment: database.php has the following config in `'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),`. So it is using the .env value, which is localhost

Answer (score 1):

Use `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1` (in your .env file) and configure your `.env` database part:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laboratory
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

In your config folder `database.php` configure the MySQL part:

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => null,
    'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
    ]) : [],
],
```

After that run these commands:

```
//---Remove the configuration cache file
php artisan config:cache;
php artisan config:clear;
```

If your answer is not solved go to the link below:

Source: [PDOException SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723803/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Thanks but I am getting a `Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory ` error when using localhost.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue and solved with the following steps.

1. Change DB_HOST to mysql
2. php artisan config:clear

It worked for me.