# Laravel is not connecting to the php myadmin database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-8

I am trying to connect laravel application to php myadmin.

When `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1` in my `.env` file

`` SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `sessions` where `id` = EO901DpTx4qUrgxMniyykEu84HrJGQESns0ySzlx limit 1) ``

and when `DB_HOST=localhost` in my `.env` file

`` SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from `sessions` where `id` = WYha9n6qWtwN0YcAACdydQSgyHeMc1PcID2Mb6Ns limit 1) ``

What I’ve tried:

- changing the `DB_HOST` to `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` (most common
  answer online, no succes)
- making sure SQL is running
- clearing cachefor `php artisan config:clear`

my `.env` file is as follows

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=haydar
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

my `data.php` file is as follows

```
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723803/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Make sure to restart your server whenever you update .env file