# Laravel: Integration tests failing on bitbucket pipelines

Tags: php, laravel-5, integration-testing, cicd, bitbucket-pipelines

I am working on `Laravel 5.5` integration tests and they are passing on local env but failing on `Bitbucket` pipelines. Here is my `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`:

```
image: php:7.1

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip libzip-dev --force-yes
          - docker-php-ext-install zip
          - docker-php-ext-enable zip
          - docker-php-ext-install sockets
          - docker-php-ext-enable sockets
          - docker-php-ext-install bcmath
          - docker-php-ext-enable bcmath
          - docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
          - docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql
          - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
          - composer --version
          - composer self-update --1
          - composer install
          - cp .env.example .env
          - php artisan key:generate
          - sleep 5
          - ./vendor/bin/phpunit --testsuite=unit-api
          - ./vendor/bin/phpunit --testsuite=unit-domain
          - ./vendor/bin/phpunit --testsuite=unit-controllers
          - ./vendor/bin/phpunit --testsuite=integration
        services:
          - mysql
definitions:
  services:
    mysql:
      image: mysql:5.7
      variables:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: 'my_db'
        MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'yes'
```

Here is the error I am receving:

```
1) DeleteOrderFileTest::apiDeleteOrderFile
```

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: insert into `modules` (`name`, `description`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (System Administration, System administration feature, 2023-04-05 09:07:03, 2023-04-05 09:07:03)) 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:624 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:459 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:411 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Processors/Processor.php:32 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:2494 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php:1283 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:787 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:752 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:615 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php:755 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php:1041 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php:756 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:1570 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:1582 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/tests/integration/database/seeds/shared/TestModulesTableSeeder.php:26 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:29 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:87 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:31 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:564 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Seeder.php:122 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Seeder.php:42 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/tests/integration/database/seeds/shared/TestDefaultSeeder.php:24 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:29 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:87 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:31 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:564 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Seeder.php:122 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Seeder.php:42 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/tests/integration/database/seeds/shared/TestSeeder.php:22 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:29 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:87 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:31 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:564 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Seeder.php:122 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Seeder.php:42 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/tests/integration/OrderLineProcessing/OrderLinesFilesSeeder.php:18 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:29 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:87 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:31 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:564 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Seeder.php:122 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Seeds/SeedCommand.php:63 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/GuardsAttributes.php:122 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Seeds/SeedCommand.php:64 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:29 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:87 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:31 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:564 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:179 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:255 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:166 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:1021 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:275 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:149 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php:89 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php:188 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:250 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/browser-kit-testing/src/Concerns/InteractsWithConsole.php:25 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/browser-kit-testing/src/Concerns/InteractsWithDatabase.php:87 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/tests/integration/IntegrationTestCase.php:19 
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/tests/integration/API/DeleteOrderFileTest.php:46
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: it might me your database container is not up or there is error with database connection form Laravel, check your database connections from Laravel

Comment: @SagarSainkar this is the log from mysql service: `2023-04-05T07:04:46.594947Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.41'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)`

Comment: You can also check logs for Laravel container

Comment: Please format the error trace as a code block

Comment: @N1ngu formatted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the failing test is the first one that actually tries to access the database, let's focus on the DB connection.

What is your setting for DB_HOST in .env.example?

If it's `localhost` that could explain why it works in local, but not in pipelines.

[Here's a reference](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/databases-and-service-containers/#Connecting-to-MySQL) that says:

> Host name: 127.0.0.1 (avoid using localhost, as some clients will attempt to connect via a local "Unix socket", which will not work in Pipelines)

This is also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22927341) with a recommendation for Laravel 5:

> Change "DB_HOST" in the .env file from "localhost" to "127.0.0.1"