# I am not connecting to a database in yii2

Tags: yii2, mariadb

I am following along a youtube tutorial for yii2 and have created a database named yii2crashcoursenew and a table named user with the properties id, username, password, auth_key, access_token and primary key id. I have added one row to the table with the values admin, admin, key1, token1. The code in the config -> db is:

```
return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yii2crashcoursenew',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'password',
    'charset' => 'utf8'
]
```

When I type admin, admin in the loginform I get the following error

```
Database Exception – yii\db\Exception
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
↵
Caused by: PDOException
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
in /Users/webdevelopment/basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php at line 705
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong and how to solve the issue? Thankyou.

Comment: Show your `login` action.

Comment: Try changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Are you sure that db is available at localhost?

Comment: it has worked when I changed to 127.0.0.1. Do you know why?

Comment: Explained in this post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9715164/1231563)