# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mariadb

I'm connecting to a MariaDB database using PHP PDO library. When running the code on PhpStorm, everything works fine, but when running on LAMPP I get the following exception:

```
127.0.0.1:45536 [500]: POST /register - Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/app/DB/DatabaseManager.php:17
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/app/DB/DatabaseManager.php(17): PDO->__construct()
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/index.php(31): create_connection_to_db()
#2 [internal function]: {closure}()
#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/vendor/klein/klein/src/Klein/Klein.php(878): call_user_func()
#4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/vendor/klein/klein/src/Klein/Klein.php(588): Klein\Klein->handleRouteCallback()
#5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/index.php(49): Klein\Klein->dispatch()
#6 {main}

Next Klein\Exceptions\UnhandledException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/vendor/klein/klein/src/Klein/Klein.php:954
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/vendor/klein/klein/src/Klein/Klein.php(645): Klein\Klein->error()
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/index.php(49): Klein\Klein->dispatch()
#2 {main}
  thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/vendor/klein/klein/src/Klein/Klein.php on line 954
```

The exception is thrown when creating a PDO instance:

**DatabaseManager.php**

```
include_once realpath(__DIR__."/../settings.inc.php");

function create_connection_to_db() : PDO {
    global $host, $port, $dbname, $user, $mysql_socket, $password;
    return new PDO("mysql:host={$host};port=$port;unix_socket=$mysql_socket;dbname={$dbname}", $user, $password);
}
```

**settings.php.inc**

```
<?php
$user="root";
$password="";
$dbname="ForoPoly";
$host="127.0.0.1";
$port = "3306";
$mysql_socket="/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock";
```

I've tried to specify the MySQL socket, but it not working:

```
$mysql_socket="/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock";
```

Also, I have enabled pdo_mysql extension and ovweritten socket in laamp's php.ini:

```
extension=pdo_mysql
pdo_mysql.default_socket = /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
mysqli.default_socket = /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

It's important to say that the host is 127.0.0.1, not localhost.

Same thing happens when creating a php test server using the interpreter

Comment: Do you want to connect via socket, or do you want to connect via host and port? You're specifying both, which makes no sense

Comment: My bad, sorry for my ignorance. By only specifying the socket the exception gets resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide whether you want to connect via a socket *or* you want to connect via hostname and port. They are different connection mechanisms, so specifying both - as you're doing in your code currently - does not make sense.

Remove one or the other from the connection string and then you should get better results.

Comment: It Is kind of weird that even when using only TCP/IP connection , I still get the exception: "PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory ". It feels like if it was trying to find a socket file, even when I'm not using localhost host, just 127.0.0.1

Comment: @JCGdev Not sure what you mean? If you use a socket, then the hostname or IP address is not involved at all. Likewise if you use hostname or IP (it's irrelevant which, since a hostname simply resolves to an IP anyway) then it won't use a socket. I don't know for sure which one it would default to trying if you include both options in your connection string.

Comment: I mean, I've read that setting your host as "localhost" causes PDO to try to open a UNIX socket. Some people fixed that by setting host as 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9715164. That's why I said that it was confusing that PDO was still trying to find a file

Comment: Ah ok. To be fair I didn't know that.  But certainly in that case I think you should not also use the `$mysql_socket` value in the connection string as well (as per https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php).

Answer (score 0):

Just found the error!,

it has to do with my file "settings.php.inc". It contains variables
for host, port, dbname...

The thing is that when I was including them, they ended up being empty for some reason.:

```
include_once realpath(__DIR__."/../settings.inc.php");

function create_connection_to_db() : PDO {
    global $host, $port, $dbname, $user, $mysql_socket, $password;
    return new PDO("mysql:host={$host};port=$port;unix_socket=$mysql_socket;dbname={$dbname}", $user, $password);
}
```

Thank you @ADyson for your help.