# mysql - update a column meet an error

Tags: mysql

I want to make an average of forex_askprice and forex_bidprice and insert into forex_midprice. like this

```
update eurusd_tickdata_2017 set forex_midprice=(forex_askprice+forex_bidprice)/2
```

But I met this error

> 2003 - Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061 "Unknown error")
>   时间: 759.205s'

There are around 40,000,000 rows in the table eurusd_tickdata_2017

[image]

Comment: It's not an error with the query, you simply don't seem to be able to connect to the server. Since we don't know how you're trying to connect, it's kinda hard to help.

Comment: there are 21704041 rows

Comment: It's nothing to do with how many rows you have. The error is saying you cannot even connect to MySQL, never mind run any queries. Maybe some of these will help (if MySQL is running on Windows) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892689/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-localhost-10061-after-installation . If not, then search on google for "2003 - Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost'" and try some of the other results which appear, in case there are useful suggestions relating to your particular situation.

Comment: @SHENGNANLI as ADyson said,it has nothing to do with your rows amount,you can only update one row to check that

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I already connect to MySQL. But every time I run this ''update eurusd_tickdata_2017 set forex_midprice=(forex_askprice+forex_bidprice)/2 '', it always meet the same error

Comment: well it seems like maybe your connection has been dropped since you last connected. Can you run any other queries on the same database? Just try some simple SELECT query to test it.

Comment: I've run this 'SELECT COUNT(*) from eurusd_tickdata_2017', and it works. I wonder maybe there are too many rows to update, so it finally lost the connection.

Comment: does it wait some time after starting the query before you get this error?

Comment: Yes, it works when I start the query but lost connection after running for minutes

Comment: I suggest maybe running the update in batches. Or perhaps you can increase the query timeout length. I'm not an expert on the latter, sorry, but either someone else can answer or you can google whether it's possible to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was the problem on your configuration settings of your database source like connection look up this video for your issue.

**https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ab25N34RO8w**

Answer (score -2):

It looks like your MySQL server is not installed. you can check steps & install from link - [MySQL on Windows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/windows-start-service.html)

Comment: This is impossible,can not image someone use `mysql` without install it