# Cant Build Schema In Local Instance MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to create a new local instance in MySQL Workbench 8.0. I already create one local connection, but when I try to create a schema the **Execute** query button is disabled and i cant right click on **Navigator** field to add schema. I follow many instruction on internet, but they all seems to have no problem when adding a schema.

The detail of local connection that I created is like this

- **Connection Method: Standard (TCP/IP)**
- **Hostname : localhost**
- **Port: 3306**
- **Username: root**

And when I click the **Test Connection** button, it says **Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)**

Anyone know what I'm missing in both step and requirement?

Comment: You are not able to login to your mysql instance because you have not configured your mysql properly, try solving that first. for the above error you mentioned, check this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892689/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-localhost-10061-after-installation

Comment: @James 10061 is not port here, it's an error code.