# In MySQL, what is the purpose of root@'my.host' and root@'127.0.0.1'?

Tags: mysql

Mysql on Centos6 (and other distros iirc) initializes multiple root users (where host.domain is my hostname):

```
select User,Host,Password from mysql.user where User = 'root';

+------+-------------+-------------------------------------------+
| User | Host        | Password                                  |
+------+-------------+-------------------------------------------+
| root | localhost   | *2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19 |
| root | host.domain | *2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19 |
| root | 127.0.0.1   | *2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19 |
+------+-------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

I do not understand the purpose of the root@'host.domain' and root@'127.0.0.1' entries.  In what situation is the Host of a localhost connection *not* 'localhost'?  I thought all local connections were interpreted as from 'localhost'.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715925/localhost-vs-127-0-0-1

Answer (score 0):

Well you could if you wanted to, edit etc/hosts and set localhost to something other than 127.0.0.1 for instance.

Answer (score 0):

If your running a webhost, your apache server may host multiple domains on the same server. In that case, 127.0.0.1 points to multiple domains. For example, /etc/hosts may look like this.

```
127.0.0.1    localhost    www.gregsblog.com    www.dannisrecipes.org    www.schoolofsql.edu
```

Now when php tries to access MySQL, if its the apache system running php, his request will be **root@localhost**. This is good! Now what if Greg tries to get to it? His request goes in as **root@www.gregsblog.com**. This is good too because we don't want shady Greg getting into our database.

**host.domain** just makes it easier IMO if you move the host. So **root@host.domain** even if you eventually separate into two distinct application and data servers.

Answer (score 0):

You use root@localhost versus root@remoteipaddress. They are used for remote host access so other servers can connect to your database.