# Why does PDO take 1 second to connect?

Tags: php, pdo

I use MySQL Workbench to run queries. It takes literally no time at all to run them. However, when I connect to the database via PDO, it takes over one second to connect! Why?

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$db = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";

$mtime = explode(" ",microtime());
$starttime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0];

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db",$user,$pass);

$mtime = explode(" ",microtime());
$totaltime = (($mtime[1] + $mtime[0]) - $starttime);
echo $totaltime * 1000;
```

This outputs:

```
1008.975982666
```

Comment: Is workbench connecting via `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` or some other name? Connection speed issues are often related to DNS lookup issues.  If you have a shell (and this is a Unix-like machine, does `dig localhost` return quickly?  `localhost` should be defined as `127.0.0.1` but there could be something weird with the hosts file.

Comment: Call `microtime(true)` to get a float value of the current time, and get rid of this whole explode-time-calculation-thingie.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I'm going to try that!

Comment: @Sven Just copy-pasted from the internet..

Comment: A database named "localhost" sounds strange to me. Are you sure this is right.

Comment: Maybe because connecting to a database and running queries through an established connection are tasks in different weight categories?

Comment: Voldemort might be able to help you @Student  of Hogwarts :)

Comment: @Subash You wouldn't believe me if I told you how many times I've got comments on that!

Comment: @DesmondHume I don't know if MySQL WB has an established connection or not... Got an answer though!

Comment: @studentOfHogwarts I can imagine. Good luck with your question.

Comment: Lesson 0: Never just copy and paste random codes from the interwebs! :P

Comment: @Sven Yes, you are correct. I just named it this because we have not yet decided the name of our project.. Doesn't matter since changing this in one include file is easy :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On windows vista and newer use `127.0.0.1` instead of localhost.

Comment: Great! It worked! Why is that? When I enter http://localhost/, it doesn't take 1 second to load? Is the browser caching the DNS?

Comment: @StudentofHogwarts: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715925/localhost-vs-127-0-0-1

Comment: Not really sure, but I remember reading that windows first tries IPv6 address (`:::1`) for localhost and then `127.0.0.1` if it fails.