# PHP slow with mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I (hope) this is a very straightforward question about what is being missed for PHP/MySQL. First, the computers are Windows 7 machines and are running XAMPP (Apache, PHP, MySQL, etc.) - nothing Windows/IIS, etc.

The machines are quick, with PHP & MySQL running super-fast. However, there is one machine where the way it works with PHP & MySQL is some kind of delay - specifically, it is essentially 3 seconds. In fact, if you remove EVERYTHING the code is doing so that it is doing NOTHING more than setting up its connection like this:

```
$db = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
```

...and there is no query or anything - just this PHP line that sets up the object, it takes exactly 3 seconds.

You comment out this line, by contrast, and the page is instant.

Anyway idea why this is happening? It doesn't look like anything is wrong, exactly, just somehow set up on this 3 seconds that we'd like to get rid of. Thanks!

Comment: Is the mysql server on the same host as the machine?

Comment: are you using localhost or the network public IP of the computer to connect mysql?

Comment: Try setting up MySQL on another machine on the same LAN. Then connect the problematic web server to this new db server, using its IP address, and see if the delay persists. This will help narrow it down to either the PHP installation or the MySQL installation.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715925/localhost-vs-127-0-0-1

Answer (score 9):

If this is hosted locally and you are using localhost this will be your problem, try using

```
$db = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', $username, $password, $database);
```

This is because of how `MYSQLI` handles localhost and `IPV6`.

Answer (score -2):

```
$orig = $_GET['orig'];
$des_id = $_GET['des_id'];
try {
    $dbuser = "kim";
    $dbpass = "kim";
    $conn = new  PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=destination', $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);    
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT pl_id FROM view_places WHERE name = :name LIMIT 1");

    $stmt->bindParam(':name',$orig); 
    $stmt->execute();
    $result_1 = $stmt -> fetch();
    $res1 = $result_1["pl_id"];  

    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $des_id); 
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $result_2 = $stmt -> fetch(); 
        $res2 = $result_2["pl_id"];  
        echo   'origin_number:'.$res1. ', '.'destination_id:'.$res2;
    }   catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: Of course you have a *reason* which explains why PDO will be connecting faster?

Comment: PDO support Prepared statements (client side) mysqli does not

Comment: The core advantage of PDO over MySQLi is in its database driver support. At the time of this writing, PDO supports 12 different drivers, opposed to MySQLi, which supports MySQL only.

Comment: First, this question is **not** on prepared statements. Second, mysqli does support them