# Unable to connect to MySQL database through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, privileges

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL database through a php script.  I have tried everything, but always end up with: 
"Connection failed: Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

I can connect to MySQL in the command line:

```
mysql -u user -p -h localhost
```

This is an example of the php script:

```
<?php 
  $DB_HOST = "localhost";
  $DB_USER = "user";
  $DB_PASS = "pass";
  $DB_NAME = "dbname";

  // Create connection
  $mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);

  // Check connection
  if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
  }
?>
```

These are the privileges set in the DB for the user:

Localhost:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*<numbers>' 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `dbName`.* TO 'user'@'localhost'
```

'%':

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*<numbers>'
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `dbName`.* TO 'user'@'%'
```

I am running MAMP on my system.

Is there something else I'm missing with the privileges?

Comment: Check your database. Do you have permission to access the database from your user?

Comment: `new mysqli("$DB_HOST", "$DB_USER", "$DB_PASS", "$DB_NAME");`

Comment: try to add ports, as in: $mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME,3306);

Comment: I tried all of these, but still the same result.  @JamesSpence the post shows the privileges as they are in the DB when I run a `SHOW GRANTS FOR <USER>`

Comment: If you use directly the names can you connect?

Comment: As in: `$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "dbName");` ?

Comment: So I got it to connect through the PHP.  It works when i change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`.  Anybody have an idea why that would be?

Comment: perhaps the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715925/localhost-vs-127-0-0-1 will give you some insights to your last question (2/26/2015 at 18:45)