# MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionTimeoutException: No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [connection timeout

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, server

How to fix this issue that I have it

> MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionTimeoutException: No suitable
>   servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [connection timeout
>   calling ismaster on '10.0.0.106:27017']

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB no suitable servers found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41644383/mongodb-no-suitable-servers-found)

Comment: doesn't work after follow the link

Comment: Then you need to dig deeper on where your problem lies using that link and then post another full question - as far as your question is concerned, the link above is the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Update your mongodb-php drive.It may solve your problem.
For windows visit https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/mongodb/

Comment: Tell us why you think this might help? Seems like OP has issues with connection and problem might be in different places.

Comment: It might be from another places.It might be from driver incompatibility too .see [Driver Compatibility-MongoDB Drivers](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference?_ga=2.210371221.1827438998.1511032572-19439424.1507887238#reference-compatibility-mongodb-php)