# MongoDB : Intermittent connection errors on PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, nginx

I have been using MongoDB for several years with PHP. Using ScaleGrid server (replicaset) MongoDB is not installed on my server.
I use MongoDB driver 1.17.2 (https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver).
Most of the time everything goes well but very randomly in the logs I find the following error:

```
2024/03/06 04:50:02 [error] 13667#13667: *2092875 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionTimeoutException: No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [Failed to resolve 'sg-hebergemeweb2-48289.servers.mongodirector.com'] [Failed to resolve 'sg-hebergemeweb2-48291.servers.mongodirector.com'] in /var/www/PROD/rewrite/versions/v0.61/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/functions.php:520
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/PROD/rewrite/versions/v0.61/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/functions.php(520): MongoDB\Driver\Manager->selectServer()
#1 /var/www/PROD/rewrite/versions/v0.61/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Collection.php(1108): MongoDB\select_server()
#2 /var/www/PROD/rewrite/versions/v0.61/class/Bdd.class.php(185): MongoDB\Collection->updateOne()
#3 /var/www/PROD/rewrite/versions/v0.61/conf/session_config.php(52): Bdd->__call()
#4 [internal function]: Session->write()
#5 [internal function]: session_write_close()
#6 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/PROD/rewrite/versions/v0.61/v" while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.70.247.215, server: example.com, request: "GET /ajax/process HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "example.com"
```

I contacted the ScaleGrid support team and they told me:

"From our side, your cluster works without any problems all year round: the information I got from online forums shows that this could be a problem in the connection string and you may need to replace localhost with 127.0.0.1. Please refer to additional information below: [MongoDB no suitable servers found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41644383/mongodb-no-suitable-servers-found) [MongoDB connection error: MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59162342/) mongodb-connection-error-mongotimeouterror-server-selection-timed-out-after-30 Hope this helps."

Replace localhost with 127.0.0.1? Since I don't have the MongoDB server installed, I don't see how to make this modification?
I don't use 127.0.0.1 or localhost in my connection string.

I see that other users are having the same problem: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/intermittent-connection-errors-on-php/14530

The problem seems difficult to resolve because it occurs randomly and infrequently (approximately once every 3 days) the rest of the time everything goes well...

Do you have any leads?

Thank you in advance for your precious help

Comment: It's done, I translated my question

Comment: This appears to be a problem of NS resolution to `sg-hebergemeweb2-48291.servers.mongodirector.com` . Is this an external server ? If this is the case, then this server may be intermittently down or suffers from other connection problems. (it happens, of course, because some suppliers only guarantee say 95% up-time) . But if this happens too frequently then please approach the server admin.

Comment: I use ScaleGrid. And I have already contacted the team who informed me that there was no error on their side.