# configure php backend and mysql database for angular app

Tags: php, mysql, angular, xampp

Currently, I am developing an Angular app and I request your help to setup the backend.
On my laptop I have installed xampp on "localhost:8080", I have created a mysql database using phpMyAdmin.
The php files should be added in the "htdocs" folder right?
The angular project should also be added in the "htdocs" folder?
If yes, should I run the "ng build" command prior to moving the project to the "htdocs folder"?
In the angular app, when the service is used what should be the url in the post and get httpRequests?
Should I use "localhost:8080" or "localhost" as hostname when connecting to the database?

Comment: out of curiosity. Why are you using php and mysql? instead of NodeJS and mongoDB?

Comment: @TAMOStudio i have a hosting account on hostgator.com who only have mysql and phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 2):

> Should I use "localhost:8080" or "localhost" as hostname when connecting to the database?

MySQL by default uses 3306 port. So the hostname is `localhost` and port `3306`

Comment: Better would be ```127.0.0.1:3306```, so you dont need to resolve ```localhost```.

Comment: @SebastianWaldbauer `localhost` doesn't always mean localhost for MySQL. It means "try and connect over the UNIX socket" if that's applicable. The port number is ignored if that's the case.

Comment: Hes running on Windows so actually it doesnt matter, because TCP/IP is used as default here. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3715946/5802172)