# How to upload csv file onto MySQL database using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

I'm trying create a create a script to load some CSV data into a database hosted with MAMP.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Load CSV to database</title>
</head>
    <body>
    <?php
        $elements = array(
            "host" => "localhost:8888",
            "username" => "inky",
            "password" => "pinky",
            "dbname" => "po"
        );

       I originally used this array to plug in the values, but hard-coded because it didn't work. 
        // $database = new mysqli($elements['host'], $elements['username'], $elements['password'], $elements['dbname']);
        $database = new mysqli("localhost:8888", "inky", "pinky", "po");
        if ($database->connect_errno) {
            die("Connection failed (Error Code: " . $database->connect_errno . "): " . $database->connect_error);
        }

        echo "Load file<br>";
        $csv_file = fopen('df2.csv', 'r');
        if (!$csv_file) {
            die("Failed to open file.");
        }

        $headers = fgetcsv($csv_file);
        $columnMapping = [
            'Name' => 'Name',
            'Gender' => 'Gender',
            'Value' => 'Value',
            'Year' => 'Year',
            'Measure' => 'Measure'
            // ... Add mappings for all columns
        ];

        while (($line = fgetcsv($csv_file)) !== FALSE) {
            $columns = [];
            $values  = [];

            foreach ($line as $key => $value) {
                if (isset($columnMapping[$headers[$key]])) {
                    $columns[] = $columnMapping[$headers[$key]];
                    $values[]  = "'" . $database->real_escape_string($value) . "'";
                }
            }

            $query = sprintf(
                "INSERT INTO baby_data (%s) VALUES (%s)",
                implode(", ", $columns),
                implode(", ", $values)
            );

            // Execute the query and handle any errors
            if (!$database->query($query)) {
                echo "Error executing query: " . $database->error . "<br>";
            }
        }

        fclose($csv_file);
        $database->close();
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm fairly certain the credentials are right as I've used them to logon to mysql through terminal, but get this error with the php script.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in some "/sites/csv_converter/test_connection.php":17
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/davidelks/Dropbox/Personal/php/sites/csv_converter/test_connection.php(17): mysqli->__construct('127.0.0.1', 'root', Object(SensitiveParameterValue), 'houston')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /Users/davidelks/Dropbox/Personal/php/sites/csv_converter/test_connection.php on line 17
```

To make things more confusing: http://localhost:8888/ returns: Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

What steps do I need to do to get this running?

UPDATE: just so you have the absolutely original.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Load CSV to database</title>
</head>
    <body>
    <?php
        $elements = array(
            "host" => "127.0.0.1",
            "username" => "root",
            "password" => "root",
            "dbname" => "houston"
        );
        $database = new mysqli("127.0.01", "root", "root", "houston");
       // $database = new mysqli($elements['host'], $elements['username'], $elements['password'], $elements['dbname']);
        if ($database->connect_errno) {
            die("Connection failed (Error Code: " . $database->connect_errno . "): " . $database->connect_error);
        }

        echo "Load file<br>";
        $csv_file = fopen('../../../baby_names/df2.csv', 'r');
        if (!$csv_file) {
            die("Failed to open file.");
        }

        $headers = fgetcsv($csv_file);
        $columnMapping = [
            'Name' => 'Name',
            'Gender' => 'Gender',
            'Value' => 'Value',
            'Year' => 'Year',
            'Measure' => 'Measure'
            // ... Add mappings for all columns
        ];

        while (($line = fgetcsv($csv_file)) !== FALSE) {
            $columns = [];
            $values  = [];

            foreach ($line as $key => $value) {
                if (isset($columnMapping[$headers[$key]])) {
                    $columns[] = $columnMapping[$headers[$key]];
                    $values[]  = "'" . $database->real_escape_string($value) . "'";
                }
            }

            $query = sprintf(
                "INSERT INTO baby_data (%s) VALUES (%s)",
                implode(", ", $columns),
                implode(", ", $values)
            );

            // Execute the query and handle any errors
            if (!$database->query($query)) {
                echo "Error executing query: " . $database->error . "<br>";
            }
        }

        fclose($csv_file);
        $database->close();
    ?>
    </body>
</html>

[Running] php "/Users/davidelks/Dropbox/Personal/php/sites/csv_php_loader/baby_names_load_csv.php"
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Load CSV to database</title>
</head>
    <body>
    PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Unknown database 'houston' in /Users/davidelks/Dropbox/Personal/php/sites/csv_php_loader/baby_names_load_csv.php:16
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/davidelks/Dropbox/Personal/php/sites/csv_php_loader/baby_names_load_csv.php(16): mysqli->__construct('127.0.01', 'root', Object(SensitiveParameterValue), 'houston')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /Users/davidelks/Dropbox/Personal/php/sites/csv_php_loader/baby_names_load_csv.php on line 16

Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Unknown database 'houston' in /Users/davidelks/Dropbox/Personal/php/sites/csv_php_loader/baby_names_load_csv.php:16
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/davidelks/Dropbox/Personal/php/sites/csv_php_loader/baby_names_load_csv.php(16): mysqli->__construct('127.0.01', 'root', Object(SensitiveParameterValue), 'houston')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /Users/davidelks/Dropbox/Personal/php/sites/csv_php_loader/baby_names_load_csv.php on line 16

[Done] exited with code=255 in 0.096 seconds
```

Comment: The error message shows different connection parameters to the ones shown in your code.  Are you sure you're showing us the correct PHP script (test_connection.php)?

Comment: And can you confirm that your MySQL server is configured to serve requests on port 8888?  (That's a non-standard port)

Comment: I should have posted just posted the test_connection.php script which cuts off at die("Failed to open file.");
        }
But I copied and pasted the rest of the code. Sorry. The error is with the mysqli, I admit it..

Comment: @RobEyre I just used the port suggested from a video. It is actually 8889 for mysql.

Comment: I suggest you share the actual code that's causing the error (obviously, obfuscate the password).  It seems this is using host = 127.0.0.1, username = root and the default port.

Comment: Also, have you considered using `LOAD DATA INFILE` instead?  Since your file and your MySQL server are running on the same machine, it's a fast and safe way to import CSV data into a MySQL table https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

Comment: I'll provide an update to a file called: baby_names_load_csv.php

Comment: Your new error message shows that you have an incorrect database name `houston`

Comment: I'm baffled, houston is the name of the db the only bit I can't work out is the host. I thought 127.0.0.1 and localhost were equivalent. I'm learning as far as I can.

Comment: You might need to change the password for `root` to `root`, because of the current error message: **Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**

Comment: When it comes to working out access permissions, MySQL treats 'localhost' and '127.0.0.1' as different

Comment: see: [localhost vs. 127.0.0.1 in mysql_connect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715925/localhost-vs-127-0-0-1-in-mysql-connect)

Answer (score 0):

Usually something in the CSV file is not quite right for the database.  While I reach for PHP to tweak the strings, I usually find that the following is actually easier.

Use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ...` with a temp table as a target.

Simple tweaking can be done with the use of @variables inside the `LOAD` statement.

More complex tweaking can be done with SQL statements as you copy the data into the 'real' table(s).

With luck, all the loading and tweaking can be done in SQL; no need for PHP (or other app) code.  Much faster; much less typing; fewer chances to make a mistake.  Furthermore, I can look at the temp table to see if the data looks like and do `SELECTs` against it when figuring how to do the tweaking.